# Smart parentheses?

Tags: punctuation, automation, nesting, text-mode

Is there a way of smartly nesting parentheses and square brackets (in text mode), so that LaTeX detects nesting relations and typesets them accordingly? I'm thinking in something like `csquotes` does with quotation marks. 
Something like:

```
\enparent{My outer layer \enparent{my inner lever \enparent{my innermost level}}}
```

with the result being:

```
(My outer layer [my inner level {my innermost level}])
```

I wonder if there is already an out-of-the-box solution for that.

Comment: [Note] I posted a follow up question on this: [Very smart parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205151/4918)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A package? The following simple macro does it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\smcount
\def\smart#1{\ifcase\smcount(\or[\or\{\else TOO DEEP!\fi%
\advance\smcount by1 #1\ifcase\smcount\or)\or]\or\}\else TOO DEEP!\fi%
\advance\smcount by-1 }

\begin{document}

\smart{Ala \smart{ma \smart {kota}}}

\end{document}
```

(Or, if you wish, not `\smart` but `\enparent`). Usage:

```
\smart{Ala \smart{ma \smart {kota}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice try, but I get: `(My outer layer [my inner lever {my innermost level}}]`.

Comment: I get: `(Ala [ma {kota}}]`. Any ideas?

Comment: @NVaughan Fixed. The final space  disappeared during copying.

Comment: Do you really need all that extra white space in the image output?

Comment: @azetina No, but I still have problems with trimming my PDF's and tranforming them onto PNG's.

Comment: I use a software call faststone capture, small and precise, and I take snapshots of the output. Allow me to demonstrate.

Comment: I would be very grateful. Faststone capture?

Comment: @azetina Thank you! Now it looks beautiful. And the suggested program is here http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm, isn't it?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Yes that's it!

Answer (score 20):

For comparison I am posting a ConTeXt solution.

Such a macro already exists, albeit for quotes. One of the good things about ConTeXt is that a feature is never defined in a one-off basis. For example, instead of defining a macro for quotations that changes the quote symbol depending on the level of nesting, ConTeXt defines a generic `delimitedtext` mechanism and quotation is a special case of delimited text. The desired parenthesis macro is also a delimited text where the left and right symbol change depending on the level of nesting. So, use delimited text to define this macro as follows:

```
\definedelimitedtext[parenthesis]   [location=text]
\setupdelimitedtext [parenthesis:1] [left={(}, right={)}]
\setupdelimitedtext [parenthesis:2] [left={[}, right={]}]
\setupdelimitedtext [parenthesis:3] [left={\{},right={\}}]
```

This can be used as

```
\starttext
\parenthesis{My outer layer \parenthesis{my inner layer \parenthesis{my innermost layer}}}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: How I envy the ConTeXt interface!

Answer (score 16):

Here is an approach which is somewhat more modular than alexurba's approach, which accomodates indefinite levels of nesting.

```
\makeatletter
  \def\@enparen#1{\bgroup\let\enparen\@@enparen(#1)\egroup}
  \def\@@enparen#1{\bgroup\let\enparen\@@@enparen[#1]\egroup}
  \def\@@@enparen#1{\bgroup\let\enparen\@enparen\{#1\}\egroup}
  \let\enparen\@enparen
\makeatother
```

**Sample**

```
\enparen{one \enparen{two \enparen{three \enparen{four} levels} levels} level}
```

**Result**
[image: sample code for <code>\enparen</code>]

Comment: Shouldn't the second `\makeatletter` be a `\makeatother`?  If not, why not?

Comment: @PålGD: yes indeed, fixed.

Comment: Nice one also. Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

Maybe nested definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\enparent}[1]{{%
\def\enparent##1{{\def\enparent####1{\{####1\}}[##1]}}(#1)%
}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\enparent{My outer layer \enparent{my inner lever \enparent{my innermost level}}}\\
\enparent{My outer layer \enparent{my inner lever \enparent{my innermost level}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]