# Very smart parentheses?

Tags: math-mode, automation, delimiters

This is a follow up question of [Smart parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110594/4918)

---

In the above mention question, the parentheses are smart so that they change they form depending on the nesting level. I wonder if it would be possible to make the parenthesis a bit more smarter. I want to see an output like that

> (one level)
>   [outer (inner level) level]

I.e. the *outer* level should change to braces if an inner level is present. To make a starting point here’s the MWE from [Przemysław Scherwentl’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110599/4918) to the original question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\smcount
\def\smart#1{\ifcase\smcount(\or[\or\{\else TOO DEEP!\fi%
\advance\smcount by1 #1\ifcase\smcount\or)\or]\or\}\else TOO DEEP!\fi%
\advance\smcount by-1 }

\begin{document}

\smart{Ala \smart{ma \smart {kota}}}

\end{document}
```

This one implements three levels with the “wrong” order of paranthesis.

I need two levels, as described above, and only in math mode but the latter should make a difference for the general implementation.

Comment: There's a package which I don't remember that provides a `\br{…\br{…\br{…}…}…}` intelligent parenthesis.

Comment: maybe the `commath` package could be helpful?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: No, I can’t find anything on nested parenthesis in the manual …

Comment: @Manuel: This one? http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=4747 Unfortunately this is not fully automated …

Comment: @Tobi No. May be I'm wrong, but I think there's a package which implements those nested changing parenthesis with a `\br` command. But I don't remember… or may be I'm wrong.

Comment: Transform the expression into Polish notation and you won't need any parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automating the over-use of `\left`, `\right` is so wrong, but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\smcount
\delimitershortfall-1sp
\def\smart#1{\left\ifodd\smcount[\else(\fi
\advance\smcount by1 #1\right\ifodd\smcount)\else]\fi}

\begin{document}

$\smart{aaa\smart{Ala \smart{ma \smart {kota}}}}$

\end{document}
```

or after clarification in comments, perhaps you want

```
\documentclass{article}


\delimitershortfall-1sp
\def\xsmart#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\smarttest#1\smart#2#3\endsmarttest#4{%
\ifx\valign#2%
\left(\let\smart\xsmart#4\right)%
\else
\left[\let\smart\xsmart#4\right]%
\fi}

\def\smart#1{\smarttest#1\smart\valign\endsmarttest{#1}}%


\begin{document}

$\smart{aaa\smart{Ala \smart{ma \smart {kota}}}}$

$\smart{aaa}$

\end{document}
```

but that seems stranger still:-)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn’t answer the question ;-) To add the delimiters isn’t the problem, but changing the appearance of the _outer_ level depending on the _inner_ level …

Comment: And can you please explain what’s “wrong” with using the delimiter?

Comment: @Tobi \left\right add extra horizontal space which is often unfortunate, and even without the negative delimitershortfall often make brackets that are too big http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173740#173740

Comment: OK … thank you but do you have an idea how to implement the outer-inner-dependence, which is the main part of my question? ;-)

Comment: At the moment the will be only the cases `(a)`, `(a (b))`, which should come out as `[a (b)]`, or `((a) (b))`, i.e. `[(a) (b)]`. I’ll take care of the number of nesting levels and I’d implement `\innerparens{b}` -> `(b)` and `\outerparens{a}` -> `[a]` to make the more complex equations manually.

Comment: For cases with more nesting levels, all inner ones can have round parens and only the outermost gets brackets. E.g `(( (a) ((b (c))) ))` would be `[( (a) ((b (c))) )]`.

Comment: @Tobi Oh I'd never have guessed that:-) can the first nested occurrence of `\smart` be assumed to be at the top level not inside a `{}` group (if so it's easy, if not it's harder requiring a multi pass system, probably)

Comment: Hm … at the moment I assume that it will live alway outside a group (except the one created by the math environments).

Comment: @Tobi updated answer

Comment: Thanks. It works with your example but not with `$\sum_n \paren{z_{\text{m}\,n} \cdot \cos\paren{\omega_n t + \phi_n}}$` so I guess I was wrong claiming that theres no grouping? (PS: May you explain, why you didn’t understand my question so I can improve my english skills ;-))

Comment: @Tobi before the edit (and even after to a certain extent) I would have expected that "so that they change they form depending on the nesting level." meant that the form changed (alternated) at all levels not just that the outer level was [ and all inner levels were ( (incidentally why do you want this, it seems very weird, and actually easiest just to code directly with [ then ( by hand.

Comment: I like automated solutions and didm’† think it will be that complicated. I guess doing it manually is much easier anI’ll go with that, but I do alway claim, that LaTeX is able to do every thing, and won’t be wrong here ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
\def\smart#1{\let\smartA=\empty
  \setbox0=\hbox{\def\smart{\global\let\smartA=\relax}$#1$}%
  \begingroup\def\smart##1{(##1)}\ifx\smartA\relax [#1]\else (#1)\fi\endgroup
}

\smart{abc\smart{d\smart{ef}g}h}  % ->  [abc(d(ef)g)h]
\smart{pq{\smart{ru}v}w}          % ->  [pq(ru)vw]
\smart{xyz}                       % ->  (xyz)

\end
```

I didn't solve more than two levels. All inner levels have rounded (brackets). Inner level hidden in group doesn't bother.

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that you explicitly (must) use `$…$` so this my corrupts the display styles (e.g. fractions etc.) … furthermore I doesn’t work with `$\sum_n \paren{z_{\text{m}\,n} \cdot \cos\paren{\omega_n t + \phi_n}}$` (like Davids answer)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. User cannot use $...$. And I don't understand what you say about `\sum_n \paren{...}`.

Comment: I mean, that the sue of `$…$` is part of your definition for the `\hbox` an thus al formulas (or parts of) inside of `\smart{…}` are treaded as inline math, i.e. factions or the limits of `\sum` etc. are typeset wrong (to small) when I use `\smart` in a display math environment like `{equation}`. The equation in my comment is an example where `\smart` seems to fail. I get round parens for both levels.

Comment: This is misunderstanding. The `\hbox{$...$}` is not used for printing but only for calculating the level of parentheses. It is not printed. The printing version respects the math-mode. See more about this in implementation notes of my new answer which implements arbitrary number of nested levels.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be very interesting especially when **arbitrary number of
levels of brackets** is expected. I tried to solve this. Arbitrary number of
levels can be used and the types of brackets for each level can be declared.

The formula enclosed by brackets are typed by `\brk{formula}` (`\brk` is
abbreviation for "brackets"). The formula can include another `\brk{...}`
(nesting at arbitrary number of levels). For example:

```
\brk{a\brk{b\brk{c\brk{d}e}f}g\brk{h}i\brk{jk\brk{l}pq}r}
this means:
(a(b(c(d)e)f)g(h)i(jk(l)pq)r)
```

My solution implements two pass algorithm.
The whole parameter of most outer `\brk` is processed in first pass in order to
decide the number of nested brackets. After first pass is done, each
bracket knows the number of nested levels in its subformula.
It means, for our example:

[image: brk1]

The second pass of `\brk` macro prints desired brackets. You have to declare
the shape of these brackets by the `\brkDecl` macro:

```
\brkDecl <left0><right0><left1><right1><left2><right2>etc<left-n><right-n><dot><dot>
```

Examles:

```
\brkDecl ()[]..

\brk{a\brk{b\brk{c\brk{d}e}f}g\brk{h}i\brk{jk\brk{l}pq}r}
```

[image: brk2]

```
\brkDecl ()[]\{\}\langle\rangle..

$\brk{a\brk{b\brk{c\brk{d}e}f}g\brk{h}i\brk{jk\brk{l}pq}r}$
```

[image: brk3]

```
\brkDecl (){\bigl(}{\bigr)}{\Bigl(}{\Bigr)}{\biggl(}{\biggr)}{\Biggl(}{\Biggr)}..

$\brk{a\brk{b\brk{c\brk{d}e}f}g\brk{h}i\brk{jk\brk{l}pq}r}$
```

[image: brk4]

You can use `\ensurebalanced` macro from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195575/delimited-arguments-and-using-a-macro-inside-of-itself/195588#195588) and math-active
character setting in order to user can simply type only rounded brackets:

```
\def\brkX#1){\ensurebalanced()\brk{#1}}
{\catcode`\(=13 \global\let(=\brkX}
\def\brkActive{\mathcode`\(="8000 }

\brkDecl {\mathopen{\mathchar`(}}{)}{\bigl(}{\bigr)}{\Bigl(}{\Bigr)}{\biggl(}{\biggr)}{\Biggl(}{\Biggr)}..
\brkActive

$(a(b(c(d)e)f)g(h)i(jk(l)pq)r)$
```

[image: brk4]

Note, that the `<left0>` declaration in `\brkDecl` is somewhat more
complicated here, becuase the character `(` is declared as active character in math.

The implementation of the `\brk` macro follows:

```
\newcount\brkN  \newcount\brkL  
\def\brk#1{\def\brkS{0}\global\brkN=0 \let\brk=\brkA
   \ifmmode \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}\else \setbox0=\hbox{#1}\fi
   \sxdef{brk.0}{\the\brkL}%
   \global\brkN=0 \let\brk=\brkB
   \brkE L0#1\brkE R0\let\brk=\brkC
}
\def\brkA#1{{\global\brkL=0 \global\advance\brkN by1
   \def\brkS{0}\edef\brkM{\the\brkN}%
   #1%
   \sxdef{brk.\brkM}{\the\brkL}\global\advance\brkL by1}%
   \ifnum\brkS>\brkL \global\brkL=\brkS\relax \else \edef\brkS{\the\brkL}\fi
}
\def\brkB{\global\advance\brkN by1 \expandafter\brkD\expandafter{\the\brkN}}
\let\brkC=\brk
\def\brkD#1#2{\brkE L{#1}#2\brkE R{#1}}
\def\brkE #1#2{\csname brk.#1.%
   \ifnum\csname brk.#2\endcsname>\brkF\space \brkF \else \csname brk.#2\endcsname \fi
   \endcsname 
}
\def\brkDecl{\brkL=0 \brkG}
\def\brkG#1#2{\ifx#1.\advance\brkL by-1 \edef\brkF{\the\brkL}\else 
  \sdef{brk.L.\the\brkL}{#1}\sdef{brk.R.\the\brkL}{#2}%
  \advance\brkL by1 \expandafter\brkG \fi
}
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\sxdef#1{\global\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}
```

**The implementation notes.**
In the first pass, the `\brk` macros inside the parameter are processed like
`\brkA`. In the second pass, they are processed like `\brkB`. The normal
meaning of `\brk` is returned by `\brkC`.

The first pass is processed inside box0, i. e. the material is fully
processed but not printed. The left brackets are numbered from zero from left to
right (by `\brkN` counter) and the number of levels is calculated by `\brkL`
counter. The macro `\csname brk.\the\brkN\endcsname` includes the number of
sub-brackets for each left bracket after first pass is done.

The macros `\csname brk.L.\the\brkL\endcsname` include the type of left
bracket for `\bkrL` level. The right bracket is stored in 
`\csname brk.R.\the\brkL\endcsname`. These macros are initialized by `\brkDecl`.